# Buscar em várias tabelas ao mesmo tempo MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, banco-de-dados

Bom, eu tenho as tabelas `professores`, `materias`, `turmas`. Para ficar mais fácil e simplificar *(pois só preciso desses dados)*, digamos que nelas exista os seguintes dados:

```
turmas (2)
+-------+----------+---------+
|  id   |  codigo  |  nome   |
+-------+----------+---------+
|  10   |     5    | TURMA X |
|  20   |     6    | TURMA Y |
+-------+----------+---------+

materias (3)
+-------+-----------+---------+
|  id   |   nome    |  turma  |
+-------+-----------+---------+
|  123  | MATERIA X |    5    |
|  124  | MATERIA Y |    5    |
|  125  | MATERIA Z |    6    |
+-------+-----------+---------+

professor (1)
+-------+-----------+----------+
|  id   |   nome    | materias |
+-------+-----------+----------+
|   1   |  Carlos   | 123, 125 |
+-------+-----------+----------+
```

Eu preciso criar um SELECT que pegue os dados CODIGO e NOME da tabela TURMAS baseado no que está inserido em MATERIAS da tabela PROFESSOR. Essas matérias estão separadas por vírgulas. Portanto, a query deve passar por essas 3 tabelas, pegando a informação do *professor.materias*, buscando separado por vírgula o *materias.turma*, para então chegar no *codigo.turmas e nome.turmas*.

Tem muito tempo que não programo, quem puder ajudar, agradeço!

Comment: Vamos ver se entendi corretamente: na tabela `professores` o campo `materias` é um campo único com as diversas matérias do professor separadas por vírgula? Se for isso mesmo seu banco de dados está muito mal construído, dê uma estudada em normalização.

Answer (score 1):

Como as tabelas estão descritas, elas não estão formatadas de forma normalizada.

Acho que o ideal era fazer uma tabela de relacionamento, que ligasse Professor a Matéria e outra ligando a turma a matéria.

Assim Além das tabelas que tem, você teria uma nova tabela Professor_Materia, que conteria dois campos:

O Id_Professor e o Id_Materia.

e outra nova tabela turma_materia, que conteria os campos:

O id_materia e o Id_turma.

Removeria da tabela Professor o campo materias

Removeria da tabela Materia o campo turma

As tabelas ficariam assim:

```
turmas (2)
+-------+----------+---------+
|  id   |  codigo  |  nome   |
+-------+----------+---------+
|  10   |     5    | TURMA X |
|  20   |     6    | TURMA Y |
+-------+----------+---------+

materias (3)
+-------+-----------+
|  id   |   nome    |
+-------+-----------+
|  123  | MATERIA X |
|  124  | MATERIA Y |
|  125  | MATERIA Z |
+-------+-----------+

professor (1)
+-------+-----------+
|  id   |   nome    |
+-------+-----------+
|   1   |  Carlos   |
+-------+-----------+

Materia_Professor(2)
+--------------+----------+
|  id_professor|id_materia|
+--------------+----------+
|   1          |    123   |
+--------------+----------+
|   1          |    125   |
+--------------+----------+

turma_materia(3)
+-------------+----------------+
|codigo_turma |  id_materia    |
+-------------+----------------+
|   5         |     123        |
+-------------+----------------+
|   5         |     124        |
+-------------+----------------+
|   6         |     125        |
+-------------+----------------+
```

Assim você faria um select fazendo joins com as tabelas professor, turma, materia e as novas tabelas criadas. ficando assim:

```
SELECT T.CODIGO, T.NOME
FROM TURMA  T, MATERIA M, PROFESSOR P, MATERIA_PROFESSOR MP, TURMA_MATERIA TM
WHERE 
M.ID= TM.ID_MATERIA AND 
T.CODIGO = TM.CODIGO_TURMA  AND
MP.Id_Materia = M.ID AND
MP.Id_Professor  = P.ID;
```

Comment: Creio que só tem sentido a existência de turma se uma matéria poder ter diversas turmas.

Comment: Creio que sim, mas como não foi dito nada se haveria, mantive as tabelas originais.

Answer (score 0):

Olá,

Se você precisa buscar nas tabelas da forma que estão pode fazer da seguinte forma:

```
select t.codigo,t.nome
from turma t
inner join materias m on t.codigo = m.turma
inner join professor p on m.id in(p.materias)
```

Esta query traz apenas as informações que forem encontradas, se precisar apenas das informações da turma pode utilizar um left join